# Can I lose Windows Partition if switching from RST to AHCI?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd, intel-rst

If I have a single SSD connected in RST mode (No RAID configured), is there a chance that I lose data in my main partition if I switch to AHCI?

I'm wanting to reinstall Windows 10 on my machine after I corrupted the system partition on my SSD. I also don't have access to the recovery partition.

What I'm wanting to do before reinstalling is to see the current state of the SSD and back up the existing Windows partition to an external drive by booting Ubuntu and transferring the files. If I go into the bios and switch the SATA mode from RST to AHCI, is there a chance that I might lose any data in the primary partition? Given that the recovery and system partitions aren't seemingly accessible anyway, I don't care about those.

Edit: For clarification, the machine doesn't boot into Windows 10 because the system partition is corrupted. I'm going to have to reinstall windows, I just want to make sure that I back up my main partition with all my data before I do so. I'm intending to install ubuntu to dual boot so that I can some other means to access to the ssd.

Comment: It's risky. The safest way is to set AHCI first, but it CAN be done afterwards with a registry hack (for Windows anyway). Make sure you have backups, and give it a go. Don't be surprised if you need to re-install Windows though.

Comment: Not tested by myself: https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci

Comment: You won't lose data by switching the mode by the way. If you don't care about the "bootability" of the current Windows installation anymore, then you don't need to bother. By the way, better make sure at least an initramfs you can use for Ubuntu includes the `ahci` module.

Comment: Does this help : [Switch from Raid On to AHCI (and vice versa) on reboot via script](https://superuser.com/questions/1368740/switch-from-raid-on-to-ahci-and-vice-versa-on-reboot-via-script).

Comment: @spikey_richie i'm going to have reinstall windows anyway since it doesn't currently boot into windows.

Comment: @harrymc hmm a little? thanks for the reply. I hadn't considered whether I would need to switch back to rst after reinstalling windows and no longer need ubuntu. might leave ubuntu on the ssd in case weird stuff happens again...

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for the reply. So to confirm, when the sata mode is switched to ahci, that only affects the system partition and not the Windows one? I didn't quite understand how you meant about initramfs

Comment: @pingOfDoom Why would that require a reinstallation of Windows? [Capture a WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of the system partition, recreate the Boot, WinRE, and OS partitions, then apply the WIM. OS partition corruption can be [fixed](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) via `Dism` and `Sfc` - if issues persist after booting to Windows, perform a Repair Install by running `setup.exe` _while booted to Windows_. While you tagged Ubuntu, you didn't state anywhere you're dual-booting - if you are, repair the BCD store via Ubuntu, but if not, repair it from WinRE via `BootRec`.

Comment: @JW0914 lost access to recovery partition so i can't access dism and sfc, which is why i wanted to reinstall windows.

Comment: @pingOfDoom WinRE is WinPE [windows install usb] with WinPE OCs vital to recovery added. Did you look at the _fixed_ link, as WinPE/WinRE is explicitly stated?

Comment: @JW0914 thank you for your reply and the detail in the answers you provided in the links. by boot partition do you refer to the system partition or the primary one that values are saved to? Also when running the dism and sfc commands to fix the os partition like the answer provided, I should be running them against the drive letter of the primary partition right?

Comment: @pingOfDoom the boot partition is the boot partition housing the boot files (it's ~100MB in size and for UEFI is the EFI partition). The commands are ran against the OS partition, which is mentioned as a comment under the commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124562/discussion-between-pingofdoom-and-jw0914).